# How can one train a neural network to classify text into preexisting classifications?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a dataset that looks a bit like the following think a shop like walmart.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+
|                     Description                     | Classification 1 | Classification 2 | Classification 3 | ... |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+
| iphone 7 order# :123595                             | Electronic       | Cell Phone       | Apple            |     |
| purchase of samsung galaxy s10 reference 32-2345    | Electronic       | Cell Phone       | Samsung          |     |
| dell 13" 500gb ssd intel i7                         | Electronic       | Laptop           | Dell             |     |
| tablet 15cm for chris t price $199.76               | Electronic       | Tablet           | NULL             |     |
| ...                                                 | ...              | ...              | ...              |     |
| 50x rolley chairs for office supplied by home depot | Supplies         | Furniture        | Chairs           |     |
| electrician cost for new building                   | Supplies         | Electrical       | Work             |     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+
```

This shape of the dataset is quite large with several thousand (maybe >100,000) rows and maybe 50+ columns.

I am wanting to a method in order correctly classify the row based on its description.

So a model based on the above dataset should take a description it has not seen before and correctly classify that item for instance:
`iphone 11 $999.99 => Electronic, Cell Phone, Apple`.

I am currently only planning on using the description to classify as a first step to keep it simple, however there are other columns such as who supplied the item that could help classify, for instance if the item was supplied by `Apple` or `AT&T` it is more likely to be classified as a `Cell Phone` for example.

I am thinking to implement a neural network to do this. I have implemented neural network before but only on the typical examples (e.g. a system to identify the numbers 0-9 [MINST dataset] or to identify clothes), so I understand the theory of how neural networks work (weights, biases, gradient descent, back propagation etc.) However I am struggling on how to implement this idea I have now.

Here are my thoughts so far:

> 1. I want to use Python, with tensorflow2.0 + keras.
> 2. I need a way to convert the text into a numerical format. There seems
>      to be a few options out there like word2vec, but I am not sure what is
>      the best option.
> 3. How many neurons should my base layer have? (With number recognition
>      each image is 28*28 so a 28*28 base layer makes a lot of sense, here I
>      am not sure)
> 4. How many hidden layers?
> 5. How many output layers? (Should I have one for each distinct
>      combination of classifications, so one for
>      `Electronic, Cell Phone, Samsung`, one for `Electronic, Cell Phone, Apple` etc. This would lead
>      to a output layer of thousands of neurons, I am not sure if this is
>      possible/advised?

I am not looking for complete answers, in fact I am aware that it is not really possible given the information provided. Instead I am looking for guidance/suggestions on how to proceed with this problem from someone who is more experienced, perhaps, in fact, most likely there are things I am not considering yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've been tacking NLP problems for almost 5 years now and here are my suggestions.

### I want to use Python, with tensorflow2.0 + keras.

Yes, `Keras` would be a good option for you to implement your solution. It should be fairly straightforward to do this with Keras.

### I need a way to convert the text into a numerical format. There seems to be a few options out there like word2vec, but I am not sure what is the best option.

Yes, word vectors would definitely improve performance of your model. But if you want a more naive solution, you can try [onehot vectors](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/). I would recommend starting with onehot vectors and then once you have a working solution, improve that using word vectors. This way you are certain that you're not introducing too much complexity at the beginning, making it easier to debug if something goes wrong in the implementation).

PS: word2vec is quite old now, there are better alternatives such as [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) and [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/).

### How many neurons should my base layer have? (With number recognition each image is 28*28 so a 28*28 base layer makes a lot of sense, here I am not sure)

This depends on the size of your vocabulary. As I said earlier, regardless of whether you're using word vectors or not, you will have to transform words to onehot vectors. And the length of a onehot vector is determined by the size of the vocabulary.

### How many hidden layers?

This is a very difficult question to answer. You will need to try different architectures and find the optimal one if you're looking for the optimal structure (i.e. by means of hyperparameter optimization).

### How many output layers?

Think this is a tricky one (mainly because tag prediction is not in my area of expertise). But I can tell you two things to try.

1. Have an output layer with all possible categories. But as you can imagine, someone needs to come up with the categories. And then if you have a large set of tags you will end up with a large softmax prediction layer. But you can alleviate that using something like negative sampling.
2. You can do this with just one output layer with a fixed vocabulary (e.g. electronics, phone, laptop, etc.). However you will need to have a fixed set of tags (i.e. vocabulary) you want to predict from. Then you can use an [LSTM](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) model to predict an arbitrary number of tags for a given description. You can produce an arbitrary number of tags as outputs because you can keep predicting one time step at a time, using an LSTM model.

But now you're assuming time dependency between tags (in the order they come) which can lead to funny results. For example if you have the same description but two different series of tags (i.e. electronics, phone, samsung and electronics, samsung, phone) this can confuse the model.

Comment: +1 this answer seems very helpful, I do wonder about the last point though, you say "For example, if you have two models with 10 and 1000 classes ..." how can I have 10 classes or 1000 classes, I mean surely I need to have the same number as the number of classifications right? So `electronic, cell phone, apple` would be one `electronic, cell phone, samsung` would be another if I have more than 10 of these classifications (which I do) how could I possibly hope to reduce them to only 10 classifications? I want network to be a function that maps `text description` => `classification 1,2,3`?

Comment: Alright, I gave another read and realized I understood your last question wrongly. I'll edit my answer so the new answer is in place